# Renault/Dacia Logan 2014+ engine temperature indicator?

Tags: engine, coolant, renault, computer, indicators

the Renault/Dacia Logan 2014 and above have indicators like this:
[image]

As you can see, the dial at the right has the total mileage and the fuel indicator only.

I'm wondering if there is an indicator for the engine temperature? I've looked through the car manual and found nothing about it.

does it exist? and if yes how can I program the computer to show it?

Comment: These indicators tend to vary depending on equipment and country. Which version of the Logan did you buy and in which country?

Comment: Hi, I've got Logan 2015, Egypt.